# How to pass credentials/parameters to exe in System.Diagnostics.Process.Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, skype

```
string x = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe /secondary /username:myusername /password:mypassword";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(x);
```

I'm getting following error when run above code in C# windows desktop application

***`"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified"`***

**Note:**

-But if I enter the url in run windows then Skype lunches successfully and login as well(window key + R and enter url in run window)

-Following string works fine in C# windows applications(with secondary flag and credentials)

```
string x = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Start(string fileName, string arguments)`
and pass `/secondary /username:myusername /password:mypassword` as arguments

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe",@"/secondary /username:myusername /password:mypassword");
```

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe", "-secondary -username:myusername -password:mypassword");         // Only Skype lunches with this line

Comment: try System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe","/secondary /username:myusername /password:mypassword");